# How can I span wallpapers over two monitors in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

Is there any way to get a single wide desktop wallpaper to span a dual monitor setup in OS X?

Comment: Thanks for the program name. In case anyone else stumbles across this, MultiScape can be found on Github https://github.com/robbiet480/multiscape

Answer (score 5):

Without splitting the image by hand into two halves (one for each monitor)? Not currently.

Answer (score 3):

The Mac App Store app [Multi Monitor Wallpaper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multi-monitor-wallpaper/id504284434?mt=12) worked perfectly for me, despite my rather unusual display configuration:

- MacBook Pro (2017, 15")
- Four external monitors (5 total monitors)
- Combination of retina (built-in screen) and non-retina (all 4 externals) displays
- 4 of the monitors are side-by-side, while the 5th is positioned on top of (above) the others
- One of the external monitors is in portrait orientation (other 4 in standard landscape orientation)

Multi Monitor Wallpaper shows you an outline of your combined monitor layout, and allows you to stretch / zoom / reposition your selected image across the monitors.

It then automatically handles cutting up the image and setting it as the background image for each monitor.

I have no affiliation with the app; I'm just a fan!

Comment: This app cost $2.99 as of this comment

Comment: It is now $10USD per year!

Comment: Disgusting, and hilarious at the same time. Nobody needs to be paying a subscription for putting an image on the background of their desktop. Absurd.

Comment: It $16/year now. I agree, it's absurd to pay a subscription for setting a wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

Their is a program called Multiscape that would automatically do what Chealion explained by getting your screen dimensions and automatically sizing and splitting the wallpaper. Although [the google code page](http://code.google.com/p/multiscape/) is down. If you want to go on a treasure hunt Multiscape is what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a follow up here so it ends up on the google indexes. I have a way to make this work for static and dynamic backgrounds using some open source tools

Prerequisites

- You'll need [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) unless you're ready to do a lot of `./configure && make && make install`
- The base prereq: imagemagick >= 7.0.8-50 (i.e., `brew install imagemagick`)
- For dynamic desktops you'll need Xcode (App Store),  [wallpapper](https://github.com/mczachurski/wallpapper), and jq (i.e., `brew tap mczachurski/wallpapper && brew install wallpapper jq`)

Steps: I'm using `Catalina.heic` and `.tiff` outputs for an example here but it can be any image format for inputs and output

1. Make a directory for your images -
   `mkdir -p ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Catalina\ {Left,Right}`
2. Extract the right and left images (left will be zero or even, and right will be odd)  - `convert /System/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Catalina.heic -crop 2x1@ +repage ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Catalina%d.tiff`
3. If you're just wanting a static background you can skip to step 7 (left image will be `Catalina0.<ext>` and right will be `Catalina1.<ext>`)
4. We need to extract the azimuth and altitude from the original image (technically you could use mp4box but it's overkill) - `cd ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures; cat /System/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Catalina.heic | grep -aoP '(?<=apple_desktop:solar=")[^"]+' | base64 -d | plutil -convert json -; cd -`

   - If this command fails, you may need to install GNU Grep to handle the `-P` option. Install with `brew install grep`—it will be installed as `ggrep` by default.
5. We need to convert the output to something that wallpapper understands

   - Right:
     `cat ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/\<stdin\> | jq '.ap.d as $d|.ap.l as $l|.si|map({fileName:"Catalina\((.i*2)+1).tiff",altitude:.a,azimuth:.z})|(.[$d]["isForDark"]=true)|(.[$l]["isForLight"]=true)|(.[0]["isPrimary"]=true)' > ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/right.json`
   - Left:
     `cat ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/\<stdin\> | jq '.ap.d as $d|.ap.l as $l|.si|map({fileName:"Catalina\(.i*2).tiff",altitude:.a,azimuth:.z})|(.[$d]["isForDark"]=true)|(.[$l]["isForLight"]=true)|(.[0]["isPrimary"]=true)' > ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/left.json`
6. Now we can just get wallpapper to create the files we need: `for side in Left Right; wallpapper -i ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/${side:l}.json -o ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Catalina\ ${side}/Catalina.heic`
7. Now just add the files as desktop backgrounds (`open ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures` will open the directory in Finder.app for you)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the ```.madesktop``` format Apple is using these days (step 2 gives ```convert: must specify image size `/var/folders/19/dj4gh90n7vl9578xxdt0h5mm0000gp/T/magick-u-7BuFCGfDWsXoVnj53eab7CUGrNV54y' @ error/mvg.c/ReadMVGImage/186.```).  Do you have an idea on how to deal with ```.madesktop``` wallpapers?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to this thread for future folks who land here from search. I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/g969vl/multi_monitor_wallpaper/) which lists some options. Notably:

- [Fresco](http://glimmir.com/app1.html) - free on Mac app store. I tried it and it worked well.
- [Superpaper](https://github.com/hhannine/Superpaper) - Open source and cross-platform (though it says it hasn't been tested on Mac, I didn't try).

Comment: Just tried Fresco. Works perfectly